# PHP: strval in WHERE clause

Tags: php

Currently I have a piece of code that functions fine as it is. But what I really want to do is take the **`<?php if strval ..?>`** part and place it into the **`"SELECT * FROM projects"`** part as a **`WHERE`** clause. I am not sure whether this is possible or how to go about it. Any thoughts would be really valued. Hope this makes sense.

```
<?php 

//  ** User ID
$userid = $row_listelements ['id'];

// ** Projects
mysql_select_db($database_db, $db);
$query_activeusers = "SELECT * FROM projects ";
$activeusers = mysql_query($query_activeusers, $db) or die(mysql_error());
$row_activeusers = mysql_fetch_assoc($activeusers);
$totalRows_activeusers = mysql_num_rows($activeusers);

?>

<? do {?>

<?php if (!(strpos($row_activeusers['assignedto'], strval(",".$userid.",")) === false)) { ?>
<div><?=$row_activeusers['jobnumberdisplay'];?></div>
<?php } ?>

<? } while ($row_activeusers = mysql_fetch_assoc($activeusers)); ?>    

<strong><?php echo $totalRows_activeusers; ?></strong>
```

Comment: Do I get this right, the fieldvalue of 'assignedto' is comma separated string of userids, and you want to check if the current userid is part of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your userid is a unique number, and I understand your question correctly, you could reach this by:

using [IN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/comparison-operators.html)  - can handle strings and numbers (they have to be unique to make this work):

```
$query_activeusers = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE ".$userid." IN (assignedto)";
```

or using [FIND_IN_SET](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) - can handle Strings and numbers is case sensitive:

```
$query_activeusers = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE FIND_IN_SET('".$userid."', assignedto)"
```

But I think you should look at your database design. The trouble with including Foreign Keys in a delimited list like this is that whole point of a foreign key is to enable you to locate the information in the other table quickly, using Indexes. By implementing a database as it sounds you have, you have all sorts of issues to resolve.

Comment: Hi Axel, Thank you for your answer. The FIND_IN_SET worked a charm. I know that the database structure is most likely not ideal. I am not really a coder and am just making a small db that allows me to do keep track of a couple projects. It seems to be managing things okay. Thanks again for your help – It's really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

i m not sure but maybe this will help you.

```
if(strval ...)
{
   $where = "where field = $value";
}
```

Now you can use this `$where` variable in your select query. it will execute only if your `if condition` is satisfy.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your code correctly, you should use SQL `LIKE`, i.e. something like:

```
$query_activeusers = "SELECT * FROM projects WHERE assignedto LIKE '%," . 
   ((int) $userid) . ",%'";
```

The cast to (int) here is done to ensure you have no special SQL characters in `$userid` - kind of cheap SQL quoting for values that are integers. You do not really need to use `strval` as concatenation into the string will convert that number into a string.

Comment: Also, this is not really a part of the answer, but the fact that you have to use LIKE there probably indicates some anti-pattern in your SQL DB structure. I'm guessing you probably need a one-to-many relation table, e.g.:

    "SELECT projects.* FROM projects 
      JOIN projects_to_users ON projects.id = projects_to_users.project_id 
    WHERE projects_to_users.user_id = " . (int) $userid;

Of course I know nothing about your DB structure but you should really read about one-to-many or many-to-many relation tables.

Comment: Of course like is not equal, and neither is `strpos` in his original code.